# MFMailComposeViewController few attachments

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, email-attachments, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm successfully sending an email with attached `UIImage` from my app, but is it possible to attach more than one image with `MFMailComposeViewController` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can save all the images in an NSMutable array and run the code

```
[mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@""];
```

for the count of your `NSMutableArray`. It will add the images to attachment field

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [_textField0.emojiArray count]; i++)         
 {
    emoji = [_textField0.emojiArray objectAtIndex:i];
  UIImage *image = [EmojiResizer resizeImage2:[UIImage imageNamed:emoji.screenfilename]
   imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

 [mailViewController addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:emoji.filename];         
}
```

Do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Call `addAttachment...` for each attachment you wish to add.